# Bad git config file .git/config

Tags: git

In my git repositiory, whenever I do any git commands like `git status` or `git log`, I get the error:
`fatal: bad config file line 1 in .git/config`
How do I rebuild that file or a new one?

Comment: According to notepad, it's empty.

Comment: Are there any commits in your repository? If not simply remove the `.git` directory and reinitialize an empty git repository with `git init`

Comment: There were commits, I ended up re-cloning from github and copying the changes into the new directory.

Comment: I think you can go to .git folder directly and edit the config file in any editor and save it. i have the same case when i trying to edit the file on command line.

*fatal: bad config file line 1 in .git/config (this issue may you have left the '[' brackets).*

Comment: Delete the blank spaces from C:\ProgramData/Git/config ....it will work fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For those hitting into this issue (I believe it's due to crashing out git mid init?) in windows, if you have a recent backup of the config file from your git repo's .git/ folder you can fix it by replacing the existing with it (any ref's added since the copy will obviously need re-adding) - not at all ideal but better than loosing all the commits.

Answer (score 23):

I know on some tutorials they ask you to put the below code, but what they actually mean is that they're the commands you type into the terminal:
git config --global user.name "NewUser"
git config --global user.email newuser@example.com

If you were modifying the file ( `$ nano ~/.gitconfig` ), you would put this into your file instead:

```
[user]
name = WilliamQLiu
email = WilliamQLiu@myemailaddress.com
```

Answer (score 17):

My issue was related to my global config which Git resolved to `$HOME/.gitconfig`, however the underlying cause happened to be irrespective of the location.

```
> git config --global -l
fatal: bad config file line 1 in C:\Users\<user>/.gitconfig
```

I have a habit of symlink-ing the config files in my home directory to a nested Git repository for maintaining the files across my multiple development environments. It turns out that Cygwin's implementation of a symbolic link doesn't make much sense to Git running under Windows.

I changed the symbolic link to a hard link and somehow this works ok. I was able to verify this by opening the .gitconfig link within Windows; when using a symbolic link the file contained binary data however the hard-linked file contains the content as expected.

Answer (score 14):

Its better to execute the two commands

```
git config --global user.name "NewUser"
git config --global user.email newuser@example.com
```

in the terminal. This in turn will update the config file.

Comment: Careful while executing commands above as you are changing the user.name and user.password for all git repositories. It will surely create .gitconfig at HOME directory(~) in MacOS though.

Comment: Once the above error occurred, if we run the above commands, there will be no success. But open the .gitconfig file, remove the existing lines and try running the above commands in the terminal will solve this issue.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem (Notepad++ showed only `NULL` characters in the file).

I managed to solve it by creating a new repo (in a seperate folder) with `git init` and copying `.git/config` over from there.

Remotes were missing after that, but everything worked after readding them manually.

Comment: I had a similar problem but in my case there was a single line full of NULL characters at the bottom of the file. Removing that line using Notepad solved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

I too had same issue, managed to fix it by below steps.

1. deleted .gitconfig file from, c:\users[username] (created backup incase not worked, but its not needed.)
2. restarted source tree and File->Open->[your repository].

Answer (score 3):

I get the same symptom. I'm using Cygwin on Windows, and when I launch a process "git clone" for instance the error message is "fatal: bad config line 1 in c:/cygwin/home/myhome/.getconfig"

The problem is obviously on the file name which is a mix between windows c: and cygwin/unix path. ;-) What is misleading is the "line 1" message while it should say "config file not found".

I don't know how this is produced as I do have neither %HOMEPATH% neither $HOME set

Comment: I have the same issue, but I cannot seem to find any way to solve it. The problem seems to be aggravated by the fact that I created my git repository on my D: partition, while the %HOMEPATH% is located on the C: partition, and git doesn't seem to like this... (not to mention the not-very-helpful error message...)

Comment: And of course, as I suspected, after creating the repository on the C: drive, I've no longer got this error...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem right after initial installation.

"fatal: bad config line 1 in file C:\ProgramData/Git/config"

I opened notepad as administrator, navigated to the file listed in the error message. The file was also blank but it had spaces/tabs so I deleted them saved the file. And now it works

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was that I edited the file in Mac TextEdit app, which is set by default to transform "standard" double-quotes into “angled” double-quotes.

In `.git/config`, the **correct** double-quotes are: " (UNICODE U+0022 QUOTATION MARK)

In my case, I fixed the following line:

WRONG: `[remote “origin”]`

CORRECT: `[remote "origin"]`

PS: If you want that Mac TextEdit doesn't "smartly" change the double-quotes, go to "Preferences" and un-check "smart quotes".

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on `Windows` was just to copy the config files present in `C:\ProgramData\Git\config` from another machine. It's new content became what's shown below, which replaced the gibberish that was there before:

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
    interactive = true
[help]
    format = html
[rebase]
    autosquash = true
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to find the exact error, `git` only shows a line number, so I'm posting my troubleshooting steps in case it helps anyone.

I had this problem trying to add an alias to my `~/.gitconfig` global file via a text editor (emacs).  I discovered my problem by instead using this command to edit the config:

```
git config --global alias.<my_alias> 'my new command'
```

I was creating an alias to show just the branch that I am on:

```
$ git config --global alias.thisbranch '!thisbranch() { git branch | grep \* | cut -d " " -f2; }; thisbranch'
```

The problem was that the `*` character needed to have a `\\` double escape in the `~/.gitconfig` file since the `\` escape character needed to be escaped (the command was now nested in a string), but I  was using only the single escape character `\`.

So my git config looks like this now:

```
[alias]
        ...
        ...
        thisbranch = "!thisbranch() { git branch | grep \\* | cut -d \" \" -f2; }; thisbranch"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in Windows 8.1 with GitHub for Windows client 2.14.*

None of the git repositories cloned in my local were accessible. Branches names, changed files, history, etc. were not visible.

Opening the Git Shell and trying to check repository status using `git status` was giving a error message 
`fatal: bad config file ... at C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_xxxxx06exx6fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\etc\gitconfig`

So I deleted gitconfig file at this path and closed Git shell and Git client. Starting Git client again and the repository is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

For me, i opened the config file and deleted everything in it. I backed up the repository and re-cloned the repository. I then manually applied my changes from the backed-up repository.

I should be noted that remote tracking information will be lost when the config is cleared. You can re-add the remote host but proved tedious for me.

Answer (score 0):

The best they can do is copy all their files in another route except the folder .git then make clone of the last commit that managed to upload and paste the files that moved to the other route so that they are overwrite and allow the new commit.

Answer (score 0):

For Cygwin it messed up my username in the `.gitconfig` file.
My username was created as domain\username and apparently that backslash is escaping the 's'.

So, if after you type `git status` you get this:

```
fatal: bad config line 2 in file /cygdrive/c/Users/yourname/.gitconfig
```

Then do this:

1. `vi /cygdrive/c/Users/yourname/.gitconfig`
2. Edit the variable **name** to show a normal name (i.e. Donald Trump)
3. Edit the variable **email** to show a valid email value (i.e. dtrump@whouse.gov)
4. Edit the variable **username** to show a simple username with no backslash (i.e. dtrump)

So the suggestion above is useful... Right before you create your git repository (`git init`), set up these variables right away:

```
git config --global user.name "NewUser"
git config --global user.email newuser@example.com
```

Because the default values are most likely not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your .gitconfig file seems to be fine (having correct data) you can copy and paste the same data again into it so that the file edit date is modified.
This seemed to work fine for me.
And just to avoid the issue in future take a backup of the same file and save as "backup.gitconfig_bak" or any name you like.

Answer (score 0):

On Jenkins, check the error message for the git-hash-string. 
Just delete the /var/jenkins/home/caches/git-hash-string git-hash-string@tmp. 
You may need root permissions to delete all files from the git-hash-string/.git folder.

When you restart the build, everything works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem after I changed the email which was on the config file. I signed up for git using  `xxxx@gmail.com`, then git generated an email for me like `xxxxxx@users.noreply.github.com`. The original email on the config file was `xxxxxx@users.noreply.github.com`. Changing it to the email I signed up with `xxxx@gmail.com` caused the problem. To solve it, I logged into my git account online, visited Settings and navigated to the Email section and located the GitHub generated email from this section that reads like:

`Primary email address
Because you have email privacy enabled, xxxxx@gmail.com will be used for account-related notifications as well as password resets. xxxx@users.noreply.github.com will be used for web-based Git operations (e.g. edits and merges).`

From the console, I run `sudo nano ~/.gitconfig`
Entered my computer password, then changed the email from `xxxx@gmail.com` back to the Github email `xxxx@users.noreply.github.com`. 
Then hit (ctr + O) to save, then hit enter, then hit (ctr + x) to close the terminal. 
To be sure it worked, I cloned the repo again using `git clone https://github.com/xxxxx`  where xxxx is the repo and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be happen if you manually edit **.gitconfig** file .
in the C:\Users\.gitconfig (you can edit it using Notepad++ )
open it and check these lines.

```
 [user]
        name = <your username>
        email = <your email>
    [core] 
        editor = <editor location>
```

you can change those line. if you add wrong line to editor variable it can lead to an error. simply you can delete this line. but make sure to get back up of it. Or you can check right code/path to connect with your text editor and replace it with new working code/path.

Then save it. (this can be more helpful to android studio users)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for my Android project. So I just did following in Android Studio: File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with push and I could repair it using:

```sh
git config --global push.default matching
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a file corruption may be a symptom of file system problems (it was in my case), so to prevent further data loss, boot into the  rescue mode, and before mounting the partition **run disk check utility** on it (e.g. `fsck -n` or `xfs_repair -n`).

But **if you are using Jenkins**, then finding the corrupted `.git/config` file may not be easy. It is stored locally in at least two copies:

- in the local copy of the remote repo cloned by Jenkins into  `<JENKINS_HOME>/<remote_repo_name>` AND
- cached in one of the many `git-*` folders in `<JENKINS_HOME>/caches`.

Answer (score 0):

i delete the [.git] from my directory and re-initialize again using [git init] and everything works for me

Answer (score 0):

first delete all contents of config file then save and exit then in a new terminal git config --global user.name "username"
git config --global user.email "mail address"
after doing these steps look inside the config file and you will see the problem is solved