# "git init" failed, what's wrong?

Tags: git, google-code, git-config

This issue is not same as "[Bad git config file .git/config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509125/bad-git-config-file-git-config)", since it failed when using `git init`.

It seems there is nothing wrong with /home/mirror/.gitconfig:

```
[mirror@home php]$ git init
error: Malformed value for push.default: simple
error: Must be one of nothing, matching, tracking or current.
fatal: bad config file line 8 in /home/mirror/.gitconfig
```

This is the content of ~/.gitignore:

```
cat ~/.gitconfig
[alias]
        lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
[user]
        email = xxxxxx@gmail.com
        name = xxxxx
[push]
        default = simple
```

Comment: Well, the error message seems quite explicit doesn't it? `simple` is not a valid value for `default`. It must be one of those suggested.

Comment: Actually, I'm using git 1.8.0 and when I first tried a `git push` with it I got the warning that `push.default` was not set, so I "Adopted the new behaviour" and did `git config --global push.default simple`. I now get this error trying to do a `pod install`.

Comment: Sorry, I found my problem, I had just installed the Xcode command line tools which has now overridden my Git version and reverted it back to `1.7.10.2`.

Comment: Note: starting Git 2.2 (Q4 2014), the error message will read `bad config file line 7` (not line 8). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26473797/6309)

Answer (score 22):

Simple was added in git v1.7.11. If your git version is older, this option doesn't exist. Simply remove it from your `conf` and you'll be able to `init` repos.

See [Documentation](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.11.txt)

Comment: I ran into this because I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 on my desktop, but running a Vagrant VM using the default precise64.box (12.04), and apparently the newest git package for 12.04 is 1.7.9.5.

Answer (score 6):

This problem keeps coming up now that git 1.8 is out. Luckily the message from git is now very helpful:

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

   git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

   git config --global push.default simple

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)
```

For example, emacs interface to git (vc) does not understand the argument 'simple', so you are better off using the argument 'matching' for the time being.

Comment: Had this issue, it told me which options I had to choose from (either nothing, matching, tracking, or current), but didn't suggest which one to use. I used current and all seems to be fine.

Comment: this was a life saver.

Answer (score 5):

Try updating config to use `matching` instead of `simple` for `push.default`.

```
git config --global push.default matching
```

or

```
git config push.default matching
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that it can be problematic identifying the issue, considering the problem is at:

- line 7 (`default = simple`),
- *not* line 8 (which here doesn't exist)

Solutions:

- Changing the value at line 7 solves the issue (`git config --global push.default matching`)
- [removing the config](https://askubuntu.com/a/282550/5470) can help too (`git config --global --unset-all push.default`)

---

But most importantly, starting git 2.2 (Q4 2014), **the git config error line number will be accurate**.
See [commit b3b3f60](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3b3f60bb672d23b9db1582395a1d29561cb79ef), by [Matthieu Moy (`moy`)](https://github.com/moy):

### `config.c`: fix accuracy of line number in errors

> If a callback returns a negative value to `git_config*()` family, they call `die()` while printing the line number and the file name.
>   Currently the printed line number is off by one, thus printing the wrong line number.
>
> Make `linenr` point to the line we just parsed during the call to callback to get accurate line number in error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Use the similar mode `current` instead of `simple` if you use a version of Git older than 1.7.11.

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I came across this when searching for the `Malformed value for push.default: simple` error I got when pushing/pulling, I figured other people may as well.

Here's a related question that provides more information for the passer-by (see my answer at the end for more links, too):
[GIT: Can't Push (Strange Config Issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083747/git-cant-push-strange-config-issue/24194604#24194604)

Note in particular that this error seems to be caused by having an older version of Git somewhere. The best solution is to update to the latest version of Git on all machines.

If this is not possible for you, simply run the following commands (as mentioned by @morefromalan):

```
git config --global push.default matching
```

or

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

to get rid of the error. This changes the default behavior of `push` operations as described [HERE](http://blogs.collab.net/cloudforge/tips-on-git-de-fanging-git-push#.U5ogepRdVRl). You *may* have to to this for `pull` as well as `push`, but it seems to be working for me just having changed the default `push` behavior to `upstream`.

Good luck!