# How to commit same project under multiple solutions from any of them?

Tags: git, version-control, commit, dvcs

This surely has to be a duplicate since its a common scenario, if so pls direct me to a good link.

I have common project (class library) that will be used across many solutions, say, a common solution which I will call `dll` shared between solutions `A` and `B`. So this is how the directory structure right now is:

```
Solution Common (dll)
      - Project Common

Solution A
      - Project A1

      - Project A2

      - Project Common #only referenced, so logical presence, not in real

Solution B
      - Project B1

      - Project B2

      - Project Common #only referenced, so logical presence, not in real
```

Now what I need is

1. a git repository in `dll` so that I can commit the changes i make to `dll` files.
2. a git repository in `A` so that I can commit the changes i make to files of `A` as well as `dll` files. (Since in visual studio I have both projects under one solution, editing them both is easy but I should be able to commit them both **together**). Also it would be welcome if I could pull any specific commits of `dll` that was made from `dll` repository, but its not absolutely necessary.
3. Same as above for `B`.

Basically I need 3 repositories so that I can individually commit in 3 different solution folders but I also need the ability for `dll` repository to be shared between `A` and `B` from which I can commit and pull etc.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. If so how would I structure my repositories?
3. How will I commit/pull `dll` and `A` together?

One solution that is already coming to me is to have one giant repository for all the 3 solutions outside its scope but that seems so inelegant as I have other solution folders too along with `A` and `B`.

Comment: Are you looking for [git submodules](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)?

Comment: @madhead I dont know what they are, but will look into it

Comment: @madhead spot on, indeed helpful, though I find the [official documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) posted by VonC much simpler to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm this is what **[git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)** ([mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032630/how-to-commit-same-project-under-multiple-solutions-from-any-of-them/15033431#comment21126282_15032630) by [madhead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750510/madhead)) are for, but you need to realize that a submodule is first a *fixed* reference to another repo.
You can make modifications directly in a submodule, but you need to:

- commit in that submodule, and pushing to its upstream repo
- cd back to the parent repo
- commit in that parent repo (recording the new reference for the submodule) and pushing to the parent upstream repo

(See more in the "[true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194))

This is well suited for a [component-based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933723/what-is-component-driven-development/933735#933735) approach, where each module can evolve independently, and specific revisions of said modules are combined in order to form a complete program.
(your "giant repo" would be a system-based approach, where all modules are writable, and in their *latest* revision)

Comment: but isn't each individual commit to `dll` solution (be it from `A`, `B` or `dll` repo) treated as individual branches? In other words, if I change `dll` files from `A` and commit and push to `A`'s central repo, would I get the same change in `dll` and `B` when pulling?

Comment: @nawfal if you are pushing to and pulling from the same upstream branch, then yes, `dll` in `B` will get changes made in `dll` in `A`.

Comment: VonC, can you clarify what is "same upstream branch"? I'm new to these terms. Did you mean "central repo" by that? I have separate central repositories for `A`, `B` and `dll` in bitbucket/github etc. Can I make changes to `dll` from local repo of `A`, then push to central repo of `A`, and then get the same set of changes for `dll` from `B`'s central repo when pulling?

Comment: @nawafal: an upstream branch is a branch on your upstream repo: see "upstream" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166 (and the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309). You usually are making a local branch to track an upstream branch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12969042/6309

Comment: Von, I will inspect that and get back to trouble u more :) Your help is much appreciated..

Comment: @nawfal: on tracking branch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4697054/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch are instructive posts.