# Git Clone trying to use repository's non-existent config file?

Tags: git, bitbucket, clone

I'm trying to clone a bitbucket repository. When I do git clone on that repository, I am getting the following error -

```
Cloning into :"my-repo-name". . .
fatal: bad config line 1 in file /u/userid/my-repo-name/.git/config
```

This directory or config file doesn't even exist, so I'm not sure how I can go about modifying it to fix it. I have my global config file setup properly, I simply have my username and email address.

```
username@unix:-bash-4.3$ git config --list --show-origin        
file:/u/userid/.config/git/config      user.name=unix: userid
```

I'm a bit of a git noob.  Any advice? Thanks

Comment: I think this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509125/bad-git-config-file-git-config

Comment: So I tried copying an older repository's config file into the directory I wish to clone to, but then I get the following error.
 
fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check first your environment variables with the command "`set`" in a regular CMD on Windows.

You might have a `HOME` (or `HOMEDRIVE`, or ...) which would still reference the network drive U:, while you are not in an environment where U:\ is accessible: you can see an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59631115/6309).